# How to catch panic for a async function?

Tags: rust, async-await, panic

I want to try to catch panic for a async function which looks like below:

```
let x = a_sync_function(param1, param2).await?;
// the return of `a_sync_function` is : Result<Vec<serde_json::Value>, Box<dyn Error>>
```

if there is any panic when above code running, I want to catch the panic and run another code;
how shall I do this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, you'd also catch panics from all other functions that happen to be running at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`catch_unwind()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) doesn't take a future, so you cannot use it.

Luckily, `futures` has [`FutureExt::catch_unwind()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.catch_unwind), that wraps a future with panic catching. Under the hood, it uses `catch_unwind()` for every [`poll()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll).

```rust
use futures::FutureExt;

let x = a_sync_function(param1, param2).catch_unwind().await;
// `x` is now `Result<Result<Vec<serde_json::Value>, Box<dyn Error>>, Box<dyn Any + Send>>`
// The inner `Result` is the normal return type of the function,
// the outer `Result` is `Err` if a panic occurred with the panic payload.
```

Comment: perfect! it works well for me.